# Converting to CSV results in [object,object]

Tags: javascript, csv, download

I am trying to convert and then download an array of objects. my conversion looks like

```js
const convertToCsv = (objects) => {
  var res = objects;
  var data = new Blob([res], { type: "text/csv" });
  var csvURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  return csvURL;
};
```

which results in a blob URL

and my data to download looks like this

```
[
    0: {sid: 31, name: "jkk", email: "kkjd@abc.com", updated_at: "2021-09-19T17:17:22.099363+00:00"}
    1: {sid: 32, name: "jak", email: "kkjd@abc.com", updated_at: "2021-09-19T17:17:22.099363+00:00"}
]
```

my download link looks like this

```html
<a href={downloadArray.length ? convertToCsv(downloadArray) : null} target="_blank" download="filename.csv">
    download selected
</a>
```

my CSV file looks like this

```
[object Object] [object Object]
```

however, when I target only the email or name etc it downloads the data correctly. I know it will be something small that I am missing!

As always any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have created a sandbox which reproduces the issue
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-night-c98et?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Try `var csvURL = URL.createObjectURL(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));` It should convert to a string formated with indentation 2

Comment: thank you for you quick reply. however I am now getting this error ```Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.```

Comment: Ah, my bad, try to apply stringify on return:  `return  JSON.stringify(csvURL, null, 2)`